# Does anyone know of an alternative to CPULED that is not connected to the AppStore?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, cpu

Just want something similar (UI/ease of use) that is a freeware. :)

I can make a copy of the app that is installed in Applications but when I install it in another Mac, it wants me to login to the AppStore. Just want to avoid that extra step. It's not a big hassle but still I wanna avoid it if an alternative exists.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what is the purpose?

Comment: @Buscar웃 The purpose is stated in the question. *"I can make a copy of the app that is installed in Applications but when I install it in another Mac, it wants me to login to the AppStore. Just want to avoid that extra step. It's not a big hassle but still I wanna avoid it if an alternative exists."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) is a free alternative that is not associated with the Mac App Store.
This program gives much more information than CPU LED does, but it is configurable, so you can decide to hide the information that is not relevant to you.

[iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) is another alternative which is similar to MenuMeters, but is supposedly better (based on comments from multiple sources). However it is no longer free as of version 3. Version 2 is now outdated and might not work properly on a newer OS.

*Please note that I am not in any way affiliated with the two programs above and have not used either program extensively.*